# Analytical chart does not display data

Tags: sharepoint, mdx, dashboard, performancepoint

I am working on an analytical chart in PerformancePoint. I linked a filter (2 levels of hierarchty) to this chart with the following formula:

```
<<SourceValue>>.children
```

Using this formula gives me the ability to dril-down and display the the children members. It works fine. However, when I select the lowest level member in the hieracahy (in teh filter), because there is no children member, the chart displays 'no data to display' message.

I would like to address this issue by customizing the filter formula such as: if the SourceValue does not have any children, return the SourceValue, but if there are childrens, returns the childrens. In short, I'd like to write a conditional statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [IsLeaf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144932.aspx) function:

```
IIf(IsLeaf(<<SourceValue>>), <<SourceValue>>, <<SourceValue>>.Children)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have figured it out. Here is the statement:

```
IIF ( <<SourceValue>>.Level.Ordinal <> X, <<SourceValue>>.Children, <<SourceValue>>)
```

The value X changes depending on the ordinal value of the selected level. My filter levels and ordinal values:
Company (0) > Department (1) > Team (2)

Comment: You have to know that your expression could not work if you have an unbalanced hierarchie (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198073%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)